# PHP page gives 404 Error although php file exists

Tags: php, webserver, http-status-code-404

I have an admin panel for my mobile application to access data. Although everything was working fine, a php file in the server started to give 404 error. In fact the file exists, but i do not understand why this happens.

File is : http://tvitrin.com/seyrifest/v1/index.php

When I check from FTP, the file is at the server.

Comment: Are you POSITIVELY SURE the file exists on the server?

Comment: I think this is related to some permission issue. Check permission for file and parent directory. Can apache execute proper permission on that.